# Is it possible to compare probabilities of 2 logistic different models with same data set?

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, logit

I have two logistic regression models (A&B), one gives probability of "person A" buying "Product X" and other model gives probability of person A buying "product Y". The training data for both these models are same but the features are different (as characteristics of product X & Y are different). So if i get probability of 0.9 in Model 1 and 0.6 in Model 2, can i conclude person A is most likely to purchase product X than Y?

Comment: What do you mean by "The underlying data for both these models are same"? Do you mean you have access to purchasing decisions with multiple choices per individual? It seems that you don't need to model proba of A to choose a given product, but you should rather model proba of a person to choose a product given its features (In this base "being X" or "being Y" would become a product feature in addition to the other ones: price, quantity, etc)

Comment: By underlying data, we meant the training data for both model are same. We tried building a single multi class classification model to identify the product user is likely to purchase. But it was not that effective .So we were wondering if we can build individual models and then compare probabilities to identify the likelihood.

Comment: Can the person buy both or neither? Would the purchase decisions be correlated? What do you mean that the original single model was "not that effective"? Do you have 1 dataset with i customers & j features, of which you used 1 subset of j for the X model & another (possibly overlapping) subset for the Y model?

Comment: 1) Can the person buy both or neither? Would the purchase decisions be correlated? - Yes. 2)  What do you mean that the original single model was "not that effective"?- The multi class model puts it into one class, it does not take into account cases where the customer can buy both the products .3) Do you have 1 dataset with i customers & j features, of which you used 1 subset of j for the X model & another (possibly overlapping) subset for the Y model? – Yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these 2 events are mutually exclusive events. I think it will be better to design one model for both. Or, you can simply add another if condition layer that picks the higher probability.
However if them both can happen in the same time you can report both probabilities. In this case this report will have a business meaning.